# How to add array into the array for json in php?

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to convert array into json format in php,
the format i want to do is like

```html
 {
      "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
          "template_type": "list",
          "top_element_style": "large",
          "elements": [
            {
              "title": "Classic White T-Shirt",
              "image_url": "http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/item100-thumb.png",
              "subtitle": "Soft white cotton t-shirt is back in style",
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "type": "web_url",
                  "url": "https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=101",
                  "title": "Buy Item"
                }
              ]
            },
```

Here is my code to convert,

```html
       $message = ["attachment"=>["type"=>"template","payload"=>["template_type"=>"list","top_element_style"=>"large","elements"=>["title"=>"test","image_url"=> "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/375/0*sepg7sXXe3zcmGvZ.png","subtitle"=>"Soft white cotton t-shirt is back in style" ]]]];
```

this give me the result like this 
[image]
I have a few more steps to add buttons type, url and title,anyone guide me please.

Comment: Try `json_encode('your-array');`

Comment: No no,  I have to add more array like buttons, type, url and title into the array, I just finished till subtitle.

Comment: If you want to add an array to the existing array, then use `array_push('your-existing-array','your-new-array');`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transform your array into json use `json_encode`. And use `json_decode` if you want to transform json into array or object. Say if you want to add new array.

```
$message['attachment']['payload']['elements']['buttons'] = array();
```